# Can't comment because of a bug

Tags: support, comments, javascript

Wherever I click *Add a comment* on Stack Exchange sites, even on my own questions, the screen gets like this:

[image: Screenshot]

without any possibility to comment. How can I fix it?

I'm using Chrome version 111.0.5563.149, but the same happened with Microsoft Edge version 112.0.1722.39.

Comment: Hmm. Does this happen with all browser extensions (and userscripts) turned off? Also, does it happen if you try in a different browser?

Comment: Could you include what browser you're using, as well as what version of that browser you're running? It looks like Chrome, but I do see an "Error" in the top-right there which might explain some things.

Comment: It somehow looks like it posted to the http endpoint instead of the https.

Comment: Something with your Javascript is broken. Since it's happening on more than one browser, the most likely culprit is some security software you have installed on your computer, that "protects" you by blocking and altering scripts it finds suspicious, which can be anything. Try to disable or remove any such software, or browse from a mobile device which shouldn't have those things.

Comment: I could be wrong but where the ERROR message is being displayed, the UPDATE message should be displayed. Have you checked DevTools yet?

Comment: @cocomac Yes. (Commenting from a different device)

Comment: @rene Doesn't look like that's the problem.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard Sounds like that's it, since my computer has a very strict filter. Thanks.

Comment: Cheers, you can post this as self answer, and maybe even share what software you're using so others will know its side effects, at least part of them.

Answer (score 8):

The problem was caused by an internet filter called [Meshimer](https://www.meshimer.com/). They fixed it now upon request (and initially only for stackexchange.com), but I don't know if they did it only for me or for their whole system.

Update: They just fixed it also for superuser.com, and they told me that they fixed it for their whole system.

Comment: From your edits, I get it that the problem is, or was, back?

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard I had this problem with Super User, so I thought that the problem is back. But then I saw that I can still comment here. So they probably fixed it only for stackexchange.com.

Comment: So can you comment on your own questions on Super User now, or not? If not, still a bug.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard No. There's still a bug on Super User which was never fixed, but here it was fixed and it's still OK.